# I am getting null pointer exception in android

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception

```
    The below code gives null pointer exception in android studio    
please help me to solve that
```

02-10 22:42:11.702 30997-30997/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-10 22:42:11.749 30997-30997/? D/TidaProvider: TidaProvider()
02-10 22:42:11.757 30997-30997/? W/ReflectionUtils: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.os.MessageQueue#enableMonitor()#bestmatch
at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethodBestMatch(ReflectionUtils.java:338)
at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethodBestMatch(ReflectionUtils.java:375)
at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.callMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:800)
at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.tryCallMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:818)
at android.os.BaseLooper.enableMonitor(BaseLooper.java:47)
at android.os.Looper.prepareMainLooper(Looper.java:111)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
02-10 22:42:11.789 30997-30997/com.androidexample.courtcounter W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000
02-10 22:42:11.803 30997-30997/com.androidexample.courtcounter W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.androidexample.courtcounter-1/lib/arm64
02-10 22:42:11.826 30997-30997/com.androidexample.courtcounter D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-10 22:42:11.827 30997-30997/com.androidexample.courtcounter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.androidexample.courtcounter, PID: 30997
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.androidexample.courtcounter/com.androidexample.courtcounter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2545)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1396)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5601)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:160)
at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:109)
at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:517)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:839)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:630)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:223)
at com.androidexample.courtcounter.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:19)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2545) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1396) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5601) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
         int team_a_Score=0;
         int team_b_Score=0;
         @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
            }
            final Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.score2);
            final Button button_teamB1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.TeamB_score1);
            final Button buttonScore3A=(Button)findViewById(R.id.score3);
            final Button buttonScore3B=(Button)findViewById(R.id.TeamB_score3);
            final Button buttonScore_freeshotA=(Button)findViewById(R.id.freeshot);
            final Button buttonScore_freeshotB=(Button)findViewById(R.id.TeamB_freeshot);
        
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (v.equals(button1)) {
                        team_a_Score = team_a_Score + 1;
                        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_team_a);
                        text.setText(team_a_Score);
        
                    } else if (v.equals(button_teamB1)) {
                        team_b_Score = team_b_Score + 1;
                        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_teamB);
                        text.setText(team_b_Score);
                    } else if (v.equals(buttonScore3A)) {
                        team_a_Score = team_a_Score + 3;
                        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_team_a);
                        text.setText(team_b_Score);
                    } else if (v.equals(buttonScore3B)) {
                        team_b_Score = team_b_Score + 3;
                        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_teamB);
                        text.setText(team_b_Score);
                    } else if (v.equals(buttonScore_freeshotA)) {
                        team_a_Score = team_a_Score + 4;
                        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_team_a);
                        text.setText(team_a_Score);
                    } else if (v.equals(buttonScore_freeshotB)) {
                        team_b_Score = team_b_Score + 4;
                        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_teamB);
                        text.setText(team_b_Score);
                    }
        
                }
            }
        
        List item
```

Comment: Reopening this question. Closing as dup of the canonical NPE question is not helpful here, as the crash occurs in code that is in the framework and not OP's code. In fact, the entire stacktrace is framework code! OP cannot possibly find the NPE because none of it is his/her code. This is a situation where OP needs help from people who understand how the framework works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this code:

```
 final Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.score2);
 final Button button_teamB1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.TeamB_score1);
 final Button buttonScore3A=(Button)findViewById(R.id.score3);
 final Button buttonScore3B=(Button)findViewById(R.id.TeamB_score3);
 final Button buttonScore_freeshotA=(Button)findViewById(R.id.freeshot);
```

is member variable definitions outside of a method. That doesn't work on Android, because this code executes at object instantiation time and you cannot call `findViewById()` before `setContentView()` is called. You are calling `setContentView()` in `onCreate()` which is correct, but `onCreate()` is called **after** the object is instantiated.

You need to split the member variable definitions from the initialization. To do that, declare the member variables without initialization outside of a method:

```
 final Button button1;
 final Button button_teamB1;
 final Button buttonScore3A;
 final Button buttonScore3B;
 final Button buttonScore_freeshotA;
```

Then, in `onCreate()`, after calling `setContentView()`, you can initialize the member variables like this:

```
 button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.score2);
 button_teamB1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.TeamB_score1);
 buttonScore3A=(Button)findViewById(R.id.score3);
 buttonScore3B=(Button)findViewById(R.id.TeamB_score3);
 buttonScore_freeshotA=(Button)findViewById(R.id.freeshot);
```